# How to keep a counter counting down despite page refreshes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, refresh, counter

I have a counter on a website that counts down. But on every page load it starts again. How do I make it continue counting down without restarting on page load locally and on every device where a person visits the public website? Currently whenever anybody refreshes page the counter restarts. I need it to not restart on refresh and show same amount of time left on each person's devices.

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Coming Soon 13</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/icons/favicon.ico"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/iconic/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animate/animate.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>
<body>
    
    <!--  -->
    <div class="simpleslide100">
        <div class="simpleslide100-item bg-img1" style="background-image: url('images/bg01.jpg');"></div>
        <div class="simpleslide100-item bg-img1" style="background-image: url('images/bg02.jpg');"></div>
        <div class="simpleslide100-item bg-img1" style="background-image: url('images/bg03.jpg');"></div>
        <div class="simpleslide100-item bg-img1" style="background-image: url('images/bg04.jpg');"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-col-c-sb size1 overlay1 p-l-75 p-r-75 p-t-20 p-b-40 p-lr-15-sm">
        <!--  -->
        <div class="w-full flex-w flex-sb-m">
            <div class="wrappic1 m-r-30 m-t-10 m-b-10">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/icons/logo.png" alt="LOGO"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="flex-w cd100 p-t-15 p-b-15 p-r-36">
                <div class="flex-w flex-b m-r-22 m-t-8 m-b-8">
                    <span class="l1-txt1 wsize1 days">35</span>
                    <span class="m1-txt1 p-b-2">Days</span>
                </div>

                <div class="flex-w flex-b m-r-22 m-t-8 m-b-8">
                    <span class="l1-txt1 wsize1 hours">17</span>
                    <span class="m1-txt1 p-b-2">Hr</span>
                </div>

                <div class="flex-w flex-b m-r-22 m-t-8 m-b-8">
                    <span class="l1-txt1 wsize1 minutes">50</span>
                    <span class="m1-txt1 p-b-2">Min</span>
                </div>

                <div class="flex-w flex-b m-r-22 m-t-8 m-b-8">
                    <span class="l1-txt1 wsize1 seconds">39</span>
                    <span class="m1-txt1 p-b-2">Sec</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="m-t-10 m-b-10">
                <a href="#" class="size2 s1-txt1 flex-c-m how-btn1 trans-04">
                    Sign Up
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--  -->
        <div class="flex-col-c-m p-l-15 p-r-15 p-t-80 p-b-90">
            <h3 class="l1-txt2 txt-center p-b-55 respon1">
                Coming Soon
            </h3>

            <div>
                <button class="how-btn-play1 flex-c-m">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-play"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="flex-sb-m flex-w w-full">
            <!--  -->
            <div class="flex-w flex-c-m m-t-10 m-b-10">
                <a href="#" class="size3 flex-c-m how-social trans-04 m-r-3 m-l-3 m-b-3 m-t-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="size3 flex-c-m how-social trans-04 m-r-3 m-l-3 m-b-3 m-t-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="size3 flex-c-m how-social trans-04 m-r-3 m-l-3 m-b-3 m-t-3">
                    <i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i>
                </a>
            </div>

            <form class="contact100-form validate-form m-t-10 m-b-10">
                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-lr-auto-lg" data-validate = "Email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
                    <input class="s2-txt1 placeholder0 input100 trans-04" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">

                    <button class="flex-c-m ab-t-r size4 s1-txt1 hov1">
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-long-arrow-right fs-16 cl1 trans-04"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>      
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>



    

<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/countdowntime/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/countdowntime/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/countdowntime/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/countdowntime/countdowntime.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.cd100').countdown100({
            /*Set Endtime here*/
            /*Endtime must be > current time*/
            endtimeYear: 0,
            endtimeMonth: 0,
            endtimeDate: 35,
            endtimeHours: 19,
            endtimeMinutes: 0,
            endtimeSeconds: 0,
            timeZone: "" 
            // ex:  timeZone: "America/New_York"
            //go to " http://momentjs.com/timezone/ " to get timezone
        });
    </script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/tilt/tilt.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script >
        $('.js-tilt').tilt({
            scale: 1.1
        })
    </script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>```
```main.js
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    /*==================================================================
    [ Validate ]*/
    var input = $('.validate-input .input100');

    $('.validate-form').on('submit',function(){
        var check = true;

        for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
            if(validate(input[i]) == false){
                showValidate(input[i]);
                check=false;
            }
        }

        return check;
    });


    $('.validate-form .input100').each(function(){
        $(this).focus(function(){
           hideValidate(this);
        });
    });

    function validate (input) {
        if($(input).attr('type') == 'email' || $(input).attr('name') == 'email') {
            if($(input).val().trim().match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{1,5}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/) == null) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            if($(input).val().trim() == ''){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    function showValidate(input) {
        var thisAlert = $(input).parent();

        $(thisAlert).addClass('alert-validate');
    }

    function hideValidate(input) {
        var thisAlert = $(input).parent();

        $(thisAlert).removeClass('alert-validate');
    }

    
    
    /*==================================================================
    [ Simple slide100 ]*/

    $('.simpleslide100').each(function(){
        var delay = 7000;
        var speed = 1000;
        var itemSlide = $(this).find('.simpleslide100-item');
        var nowSlide = 0;

        $(itemSlide).hide();
        $(itemSlide[nowSlide]).show();
        nowSlide++;
        if(nowSlide >= itemSlide.length) {nowSlide = 0;}

        setInterval(function(){
            $(itemSlide).fadeOut(speed);
            $(itemSlide[nowSlide]).fadeIn(speed);
            nowSlide++;
            if(nowSlide >= itemSlide.length) {nowSlide = 0;}
        },delay);
    });


})(jQuery);
````

The counter format looks like

[image]

So what would I need to change in my code so that the counter starts from 35 days 19 hours and counts down to 0 days 0 hours without restarting on refresh. How to count the time End - Current = Remaining for this ? Thanks

The end needs to be exactly 35 days from when the website is first deployed by me , on netlify and opened. Exactly 35 days. End date is same of all users. Exactly 35 days or 50400 minutes

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: @freedomn-m why? Simply count the time *`End - Current = Remaining`*. See OP's image: https://imgur.com/l8ELVNa

Comment: Thanks @RokoC.Buljan ,. How would I be able to do that? What would I need to change in my code?

Comment: Please avoid posting code that has nothing to do with your issue. Try always to create a [mcve].

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan frankly there was **way too much code** to bother seeing what OP was *actually* trying to do, so went on the **description of the problem**, which states "*whenever anybody refreshes page the counter restarts*"  (and don't get me started on all those stupid comment break lines making it even more unreadable)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Noted. Thanks. To be able to count the time End - Current = Remaining how would I be able to do it?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan took me a while to find what image you were referring to when you said "see OPs image".  Worth an edit I think.

Comment: @JohnDiego do you have a specific date?  (ie 35 days from today is 34 days from tomorrow)  Or do you want it be 35 days from when the user **first opens the page** (so if I open today it's 35 days, if I open tomorrow it's 34 days (as it was 35 today), but if someone else first open tomorrow it's 35 days (from tomorrow))?  So the end-date will be based on when the user first opens the page?  Or the end-date is the same for all users?

Comment: The end needs to be exactly 35 days from when the website is first deployed by me , on netlify and opened. Exactly 35 days. End date is same of all users. Exactly 35 days or 50400 minutes @freedomn-m

Comment: Please add that to your question - it's a *very* different question from the one you've actually asked.

Comment: You need to set the endtime correctly - from what I can tell from all that code that's this bit `/*Set Endtime here*/` by setting the `endtimeYear`, `endtimeMonth` etc.  If you could update your code in your question to be the minimal code required to reproduce the issue (ie enough to show the count down timer and nothing else) then it should be easy enough to provide an answer.  But you'll need to define that value before you "deploy" - there's no way to know "when the website is first deployed" using just javascript/jquery.

Comment: @freedomn-m Much appreciated. Now, forget about WHEN the website is first deployed, my bad. I just want a counter (with Days, hours, minutes, second) that just keeps on going till 0 days, for exactly 35 days, so starts at day 35, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds. It should be with reference to end date, and not when users refresh, visit or when I deploy.

Comment: @freedomn-m Please do respond when you can!

Comment: Honestly, there's too much code to provide a clean answer and no idea where you're getting `countdowntime.js` from.  But at an untested guess, change your .countdown100 to `$('.cd100').countdown100({ endtimeYear: 2020, endtimeMonth: 7, endtimeDate: 12, endtimeHours: 19, endtimeMinutes: 0 });`

Comment: Thanks. That works but instead of endtimemonth:7 it was 8.

Comment: @freedomn-m And if I do this, what would I need to change https://pastebin.com/EtUWNA8H to?

Comment: I made a guess that javascript months are 0-based - if your/3rd party plugin wants to go against that convention, then that's its prerogative.  I don't have access to pastebin.

Comment: this link then https://hastebin.com/eqibocivej.cs what would I need to change here if I change  .countdown100 to $('.cd100').countdown100({ endtimeYear: 2020, endtimeMonth: 8, endtimeDate: 12, endtimeHours: 19, endtimeMinutes: 0 });? Thanks

Comment: Ah, that is just the html and it will be shown on the page  for like couple of milliseconds and then counter. I got to know by refreshing page multiple times so it is not noticeable when visiting website. @freedomn-m . All works

Answer (score 0):

one option is to update count to localstorage. When page loads, check local storage and if existing count found, you can srart from there.

Comment: Or simply just have a proper counter based on the Client's date and the End date.

Comment: How can I have a proper counter based on the client's date and my end date What would I need to change in my code?

Comment: This does answer the question as asked *"how to keep a counter counting down"* (and the rest of the question *text*) - unfortunately OP doesn't want this *at all* and has not worded the question very well and it appears you've been downvoted on something that wasn't actually *asked*, which is a bit unfair - OP wants a countdown to a specific date/time, but the end date/time is being reset each time (as it's hardcoded to 35 days instead of an end date)

Comment: So what would I need to change in code so it starts 35 days and 19 hours (as it is now) and keeps on going regardless of refresh to 0 days and 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds ? @freedomn-m . And I did not downvote Kiran.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, `localStorage.setItem("myKey", "myValue")` and `localStorage.getItem("myKey")`.

Also don't get in the habit of using CSS classes like `p-b-40` for `padding-bottom: 40px`.

EDIT:
Here is a simple way of doing the countdown the way you want:

```
// TODO: on page load.
const MS_IN_SEC = 1000;
const MS_IN_MIN = MS_IN_SEC * 60;
const MS_IN_HOUR = MS_IN_MIN * 60;
const MS_IN_DAY = MS_IN_HOUR * 24;

const INTERVAL_TIMEOUT_MS = 1000;

const CURRENT_DATE = new Date();
const endDate = new Date( 2020, 7, 12 ); // end date (don't use a string).
let diffInMs = endDate.getTime() - CURRENT_DATE.getTime();

const ID = setInterval(()=>{
  diffInMs -= INTERVAL_TIMEOUT_MS;

  if( diffInMs <= 0 ) { // end date reached / passed.
    clearInterval(ID);
    return;
  }

  // calc the days / hours / mins / secs.
  const daysLeft = Math.floor( diffInMs / MS_IN_DAY );
  const hoursLeft = Math.floor( diffInMs % MS_IN_DAY / MS_IN_HOUR );
  const minutesLeft = Math.floor( diffInMs % MS_IN_HOUR / MS_IN_MIN );
  const secondsLeft = Math.floor( diffInMs % MS_IN_MIN  / MS_IN_SEC );

  // TODO: set the countdown elements in the document here.
  console.log(`${daysLeft} days ${hoursLeft} hours ${minutesLeft} minutes ${secondsLeft} seconds`);

}, INTERVAL_TIMEOUT_MS);
```

Comment: Ah I didn't fully understand what you are trying to achieve, you don't in fact need to store anything locally, simply count down to and end date? Apologies if my comment on CSS class names offended anyone.

Comment: Thanks. How would I count down to and end date? What would I need to change in my code? @stevenmcgovern

Comment: @stevenmcgovern completely agree with the classname issue - classes should be for what they are for, not what they do - but I'd probably add this as a comment on the question with a "offtopic:" prefix as it's not part of the answer.

Comment: This does answer the question as asked *"how to keep a counter counting down"* (and the rest of the question *text*) - unfortunately OP doesn't want this *at all* and has not worded the question very well and it appears you've been downvoted on something that wasn't actually *asked*, which is a bit unfair - OP wants a countdown to a specific date/time, but the end date/time is being reset each time (as it's hardcoded to 35 days instead of an end date)

Answer (score 0):

Super late to the boat on this one but if anyone ever comes across this issue on Colorlib templates here is how you set the countdown to a specific time.

Set the Timezone you want that add the Day, Month, Year, Hour etc. you want to to count down to. Without a time zone, it will be set to start at a static 35 days every time to page loads (which is great for demo purposes only).

The below example will count down to `5th of December 2021 @ 4PM UTC`

```
        $('.cd100').countdown100({
            /*Set Endtime here*/
            /*Endtime must be > current time*/
            endtimeYear: 2021,
            endtimeMonth: 12,
            endtimeDate: 5,
            endtimeHours: 18,
            endtimeMinutes: 0,
            endtimeSeconds: 0,
            timeZone: "UTC" 
            // ex:  timeZone: "America/New_York"
            //go to " http://momentjs.com/timezone/ " to get timezone
        });
```